# php language file static array - utf8 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

On a website I use language files that look like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function lang($phrase){
    static $lang = array(

        //MENU-TOP
        'PHRASE_1' => 'Kezdőlap'

    );

    return $lang[$phrase];
}

?>
```

and call the right translation on the website with

```
<?php echo lang('PHRASE_1'); ?>
```

The website I call the translation from is in UTF-8, and other phrases that come from the database are being displayed correctly. However, the phrases from the language file are corrupt (? characters etc).

Anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Then your language file isn't encoded properly. Check your "Save as" dialog, that's where the setting often is

Comment: @Pekka웃: hey, thx so much, this was the solution. Could you submit an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then your language file isn't encoded properly.

Check your "Save as" dialog, that's where the setting is in most IDEs and text editors.